# How to insert blank lines in eclipse cheatsheet?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

[cheatsheet screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ytzM.jpg)

How do I put a blank line in the image like the one marked in black, and how do I enter the code like the one marked in yellow?

Comment: The cheatsheet can be found at https://github.com/eclipse-jdt/eclipse.jdt/blob/master/org.eclipse.jdt/cheatsheets/HelloWorldSWT.xml .

Comment: Wow, that's great~!!